# Datatables - Local Server Side Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

One of the queries I currently run to populate a Datatable is pretty resource intensive, so I am trying to reduce the amount of load on my database by reducing the amount of ajax calls for pagination, sorting, searching etc...

I currently do a single ajax call to get a json array of the entire dataset(received by the browser in a couple of seconds), plug that in to Datatables and have it render the whole set.

A problem occurs when there are tens of thousands of records, the browser hangs for close to 20 seconds before rendering the data.

Is there some sort of middle ground, where datatables doesn't load the whole set from the json array, and instead uses the json array as a sort of local server source for the data. So in practice it would retrieve the first 10 rows from the json array, render them, and when the next page is clicked, or a search is initiated it goes back to the json array for the data instead of the server?

This sounds like a pretty simple solution, but I have not managed to find a function for this looking through the documentation. Is there a way to accomplish this with Datatables, natively or not?

Comment: probably you have yours reasons to do it in that way, but with that amount of data you should use ajax calls for each user action, just load the first page, and if the user change page or add some filter, sorting...make a new call to the server. Keep on js thousands of records is not a good solution for me...

Comment: @cralfaro Yeah like I said it's a really expensive query, having the query run over and over and over for the multiple small interactions with the table doesn't seem like the best solution. Seem easier to have all the data locally(which the browser receives and stores very quickly), and then have Datatables cherry pick from it.

Comment: you also could consider do the query with the page pagination, then your query wont be very expensive, i recommend you to use the query approach because handle this amont of data by the browser is too much and your app will depend on the browser capacity, also if your data get bigger is not scalable...#